# Access intranet via VPN from Windows 7 Home Premium SBS2003

Tags: windows-7, vpn, windows-server-2003

Our office runs SBS2003 and I have always been able to access 'http://companyweb' via VPN. I have now bought a new laptop that runs Windows 7 Home Premium. 
I am able to connect via VPN. However i can no longer access companyweb or an other intranet site. Outlook also no longer connects to Exchange over VPN.
I know I am connected as my public IP is my office server's public IP over VPN. My vpn dns is the server ip on the local office network
Can anyone help please?

Comment: Any idea if the host file on your old PC was filled with entries to make these connections possible?  Can you ping the Exchange server or any of your other servers once connected to VPN?

Comment: I can ping the server fine when connected, no idea about the host file tho.

Comment: I can even access all shared folders on the office network with run>\\SERVERNAME\

Comment: I resolved it. For some reason I had to add a DNS suffix to my VPN connection for it to work. The suffix being my domain.local
Got the answer from another forum but still don't exactly understand why. Thanks tho

Comment: Odd... glad you were able to figure it out!